# Python Transfer Function with exponential term in the numerator

Tags: python, controls, transfer-function

[transfer function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef93Q.jpg)
How would I input this transfer function in python? I'm having trouble with the exponential term in the numerator.
I'm currently using the python control systems library; is it possible to input the exponential term with this library?
As far as I know, you can only input the transfer function through a list of coeficients like this

```
Hlc = control.tf(eqnum , eqden)
```

eqnum and eqden are both a list of numbers

I've red through the documentation of python control systems library

Comment: Doesn't seem like that interface supports non-polynomial transfer functions. You could ask the maintainers if there is a way to model a transfer function like yours. https://github.com/python-control/python-control

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do it like so:

```
num_pade, den_pade = control.pade(r,10)
TFe = control.tf(num_pade,den_pade)
```

The r is the coefficient of the expo with this you get fractional approximation of the expo.
The 10 is for the precision of the approximation.
TFe equals in this case e^(-rp) (approximately).
if you want a transfer function with a poles do as follows:

```
num, den = [1],[a, 1]
TF2 = control.tf(num,den)
TF = control.series(TFe,TF2)
```

TF equals to, in this case, e^(-rp)/(ap+1).
p = jw sometimes its reffered to as s.